# JAXB generating invalid Javadoc - @link byte[]

Tags: jaxb, javadoc

I'm using the maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate JAXB classes from a WSDL file. Unfortunately the automatically generated **Javadoc** is not Java 8 compliant as it generates the following invalid links:

```
/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link byte[]}{@code >}}
 * 
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", name = "base64Binary")
public JAXBElement<byte[]> createBase64Binary(byte[] value) {
    return new JAXBElement<byte[]>(_Base64Binary_QNAME, byte[].class, null, ((byte[]) value));
}
```

The `@link byte[]` reference fails as a missing reference. Unfortunately I don't know if this is being generated by the maven plugin, or JAXB itself.

I don't want to turn of Javadoc linting for my project. Any help on how to fix this without having to resort to adding jxb:javadoc elements all over my WSDL would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `maven-jaxb2-plugin` only calls XJC, it does not generate any code on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the erroneous `javadoc` tags were in the file `ObjectFactory.java`, and I don't use the `ObjectFactory` class. So I modified my build script to delete the file after it was generated and before running `javadoc`.

Cutting the Gordian knot, or using a hammer since it was the only tool I had? You decide.